# Linq - How to get all children

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a Type **MenuItem** that has one-to-many relationship with itself through **Children** property.

```
public class MenuItem
{
    //Some properties

    public IList<MenuItem> Children{get; set;}
}
```

Now Is there any way in Linq-To-NH to fetch all children until leaf level (not just direct children) for a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to have a way to do it using `join fetch`:

http://ayende.com/blog/4151/nhibernate-tips-tricks-efficiently-selecting-a-tree

http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/16/how-to-map-a-tree-in-nhibernate